# What is a good javascript calendar that can potentially store user data over time?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, calendar

I am working on a commission calculator and would like to know how I take sales the users would input and save them to return MTD/YTD commission amounts?

I am currently working on learning the html/javascript for the input form, but now I am wondering how I can link the sales data to a nice calendar.

Comment: do u have any rough mock UIs.. that can help

Comment: @Amitd So far I have an input form where i have been sandboxing the javascript so I do not have much yet. My main task I feel is how I can link a calendar from one page to a date specific form on another page

Comment: may be this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087537/what-are-some-free-web-based-open-source-calendar-solutions

Comment: @Amitd, thanks for the response, I found this on Google and I think this was more of what I was looking for: [link ](http://javascriptcalendar.org/javascript-date-picker.php).  I need basic calendar functionality which will then allow the user to select a day they worked and I guess propose a conditional statement enter data, or cancel.  if enter data is true, then user uses calculator function.  Upon submitting data, values are then stored for that day.  Then on user home page, they can see their MTD and YTD commission amounts.

Comment: http://javascriptcalendar.org/  I hope to build off of this one I found on Google just now.  This calendar seems pretty portable and lightweight.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You have two main directions to go:

1. You can save sales data to a central server so that the user can login and view their info from any computer and so that it is securely saved.
2. You can save sales data on the local computer in Local Storage (modern browsers only).  Local Storage is generally persistent, but not guaranteed to last forever and it is ONLY on that particular local computer.

If this is an important business application, I would generally think you would save the data to a central server in which case you would need a server and a server-side language (perhaps PHP) and database (perhaps mySQL) that you could receive the form data and store securely with a server-side web application.  You would probably also need to create a login system so that users got access only to their own data.

Comment: Option 1 is where I would like to take this project. This is not intended to be a primary method of reporting, but rather a supplementary system for individual field sales reps to monitor their individualised progress. Ideally I want to create the content in bootstrap/css/javascript (and with your advice, php mySQL) and hopefully use something like maybe this mobi xdk for mobile app dev.  My next question is what are some good resources for developing server-side, calendar-based, commission management system with?

Comment: Wow was I ambitious back then...and realistically just to help my colleagues out have access to information to help their sales numbers out!  Way cool me